# How to handle data-target value with special characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am implementing one bootstrap pop-up. And I am putting some value with special characters in data-target. These value coming from DB, This pop-up implementing through loop.

I tried with w3school. How can I open pop-up with special characters.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my(Modal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="my(Modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If remove the `(` then it will work. But these id is not my hand, these id coming from API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the special characters in order to let jQuery know that you want to use the character the way it is and it should not consider as a syntax error.

```
function escapeString(str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/[\\"')(]/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0')
}
// Add special characters here       ^ -- after \\
// This allows single, and double quotes, 
// opening, and closing parentheses.
```

Wrap your target value with the above function:

```
data-target="+ escapeString(targetValue) +"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to "escape" the special characters in the selector. This:

```
data-target="#my(Modal"
```

Should be:

```
data-target="#my\(Modal"
```

Or:

```
data-target="#my\000028Modal"
```

Your sample code with just one `\` added:

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my\(Modal">Open Modal</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="my(Modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have one doubt, If multiple bracket or commas will come then it should work?

Comment: See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes - basically any character that has special meaning in CSS e.g. `,~+:;` must be escaped. An id such as `my(Modal).foo.bar` would become `my\(Modal\)\.foo\.bar`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="rule in ruleDetails">
  <div>{{rule.name}} <i data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{ rule.name }}"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="{{ rule.name }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"></div> 
</div>

I have special characters in rule.name for example: 'as-copy(1) from test data' 
which is bounded with id attribute of bootstrap modal. By this UI modal or popup 
is not opening and displayed rule name. Please help how to trim or escape 
special characters here?
```